# Access violation trying to create an SFML window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, window, sfml, access-violation

I have followed (twice, now) the [setup guide](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php) for getting SFML up and running in Visual Studio. I have made sure that the proper .lib files and directories are being pointed to in the project's settings and that the required .dll's are present in the application's working directory, as per the guide.

I am trying to run the following: (ambitious, I know...)

```
#include "stdio.h";
#include <iostream>;
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>;

int main ()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode( 640, 480 ), "Title" );
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Compile is successful, but as soon as the application starts, I get:

> Exception thrown at 0x56D5EEB6 (sfml-system-d-2.dll) in D20 RPG.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD8.

With the first line commented, the application starts and finishes without a problem.

Do I need to locate the SFML source and compile it myself? It is a fairly sprawling library with a lot of dependencies, so that's something I've been avoiding unless someone thinks it might help. My experience with C++ and VS is shallow enough that I think I'd be more likely to introduce more problems before solving this one.

Comment: Which IDE and Compiler do you use ? As far as I remember, SFML has different downloads for each Compiler.

Comment: Visual Studio Community 15 (version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1). Compiler would be whatever compiler it uses for an empty Visual C++ project. I'm not actually sure where I'd look to for more information on that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code working by creating a new empty console application project and using the NuGet package manager interface to install the sfml-graphics, sfml-window, and sfml-system packages.

Comment: Probably wrong libraries downloaded. Make sure you selected 32-bit SFML if you created a 32-Project in Visual Studio (Or as you did just use nuget). That is for most programs the best choice.